# C# syntax issue - trying to add value to data row

Tags: c#, gridview, datarow

I am trying to code a sort routine against a dynamicaly populated gridview names Users. I have a syntax error in the C# code where I am trying to populate a column in a row of a the datatable.

```
    for (int j = 0; j <= Users.Rows.Count - 1; j++) 
    { 
        DataRow dr = default(DataRow); 
        GridViewRow row = Users.Rows[j]; 
        dr = dt.NewRow(); 
        DataView dvUsers = new DataView(dt); 

        for (int i = 0; i <= row.Cells.Count - 1; i++) 
        { 
            dr.Item(i) = row.Cells[i].Text; 
        } 

        dt.Rows.Add(dr); 
    }
```

Error message:

> System.Data.DataRow does not contain a definition for "Item"

Can someone help with the correct syntax to assign this value to the datarow?

I am new to C#

thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change the line

```
dr.Item(i) = row.Cells[i].Text;
```

to

```
dr[i] = row.Cells[i].Text;
```

Assuming the columns in the data table match the ordering of the cells in the table.

`()` are used to call methods, while `[]` indicates an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx).  This is the reason for the compile error.  There isn't a method `Item` on `DataRow`, it is an indexer.

**EDIT**

Changed `dr.Item[i]` to `dr[i]`.  As explained in the comments, `Item` is the default indexer, so you don't specify the property, the index provided to the object itself will be applied to the `Item` indexer.

Comment: This line of code........dr.Item[i] = row.Cells[i].Text;.......produces the same error.

Comment: It's `dr[i] = row.Cells[i].Text`. *Item* is the default indexer, so it's applied as an indexer to the instance of the object itself. You don't specify the property.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`dr[i] = row.Cells[i].Text;`